# special characters in folder names on NAS on different Mac Systems

Tags: macos, nas, shared-folders

NAS QNAP TVS-882T has a very large legacy folder structure with lots of special characters.

```
"some example -> goes here <<ABC!!>>"
```

Characters causing problems are mainly `/|:\?><*` and whitespace or `.` at the end of the foldername.

Older system

```
iMac ca. 2019 Intel
macOS 10.14
```

displaying existing folders and creating new ones with special characters with no problems.

Newer system

```
Mac Mini M1
macOs 11.5.2
```

- cannot display folder names in finder
- cannot access files in special-character folders.
- can create new folders with special characters (which have placeholder characters on the Intel mac)

Any ideas what would cause that inconsistency between the two systems or how to fix it?

Comment: There are two possibilities that come to mind. It is possible that your older iMac was using something (HFS+?) other than APFS (Apple File System). Might be unlikely considering APFS has been in use since 10.12. Could also be different protocols (SMB and AFP) being used to connect to the NAS. You may also benefit from a bulk rename tool that can help you fix these paths to something a bit less problematic. Hope I gave you some ideas to pursue.

Comment: @JimDiroffII 
yes - It was actually smb vs afp - thanks a ton! Do you like to add that as an answer ?

Comment: Which protocol ended up working? SMB or AFP?

Comment: afp, since that's were the legacy folder structure was created in. thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be different protocols (SMB and AFP) being used to connect to the NAS.

As it looks like switching the protocol fixed the issue, here is a bit more detail on SMB vs AFP for future readers.

To provide more detail on SMB vs AFP:

**SMB (Server Message Block):**

- SMB is a network file sharing protocol that allows applications on a computer to read and write to files and request services from server programs in a computer network.
- SMB is the default protocol used by Windows-based computers for file sharing.
- Apple introduced support for SMB in macOS Lion (10.7) and later versions, making it the default file sharing protocol for macOS.
- SMB handles special characters differently than AFP, which can lead to issues when accessing files or folders with special characters, especially if the NAS or file server is not configured correctly for SMB.

**AFP (Apple Filing Protocol):**

- AFP is a proprietary network protocol developed by Apple for file services on macOS.
- AFP was the default protocol for Mac file sharing until macOS Lion (10.7), after which Apple started transitioning to SMB.
- AFP handles Mac-specific file attributes and special characters differently than SMB. This can lead to better compatibility with older Mac systems and NAS devices optimized for AFP.

For some additional reference, check these links:

- [Naming Conventions - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions)
- [AFP vs SMB - QNAP](https://www.qnap.com/en-in/how-to/faq/article/why-do-file-or-folder-names-appear-different-when-i-access-the-nas-using-afp-and-smb)